# lotus agent detachs the attachements (EmbeddedObjects)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

my lotus agent detachs the attachements. Actually, it works almost well exception the mails sended from by "**xxx@aol.fr**"

```
Set rtitem = curdoc.GetFirstItem("Body")
If Not rtitem Is Nothing Then
    If Isarray( rtitem.EmbeddedObjects ) Then 
        Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
            If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then 
                fullpath = path + o.source
                Call o.ExtractFile(fullpath) 
            End If
        End Forall
    End If
End If
```

I did debug this agent and i saw the test "Isarray(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects)" didn't pass. It means rtitem.EmbeddedObjects isn't an array, although the mail has ready the attachements!

I don't know why ?

I seached a lot of on google and i have just found a similar problem [how to check for rtitem has embeddedObjects but object has no objects](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/b074ad93fb6a714f8525731700590a42?OpenDocument)

and i tried the hint of this [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/90867248430e17b085257317005dac9c?OpenDocument)

```
    'test
    Dim vEval As Variant
    Dim embObj As NotesEmbeddedObject
    vEval = Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", curdoc)
    ForAll v In vEval
        LogInfo("detacheFichier() v=" & v)
        If v <> "" Then
            Set embObj = curdoc.GetAttachment(v)
            Call embObj.ExtractFile(pathDir + pathFile & v)
        End If
    End ForAll
```

it works well. i am so very happy
but the last one: i don't why the previous code doesn't work

thanks a lot 
best regards
dsea

Answer (score 0):

The help documentation of `EmbeddedObjects` property says:

> Returns empty if the rich text item does not contain embedded objects.

Rather than `Isarray(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects)` use `IsEmpty(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects)`.

Comment: i had used `IsEmpty(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects)` that returns True, but why? the email (sended from **xxx@aol.fr**) has really an attachement! And `curdoc.HasEmbedded` returns True.

Comment: I think attachment is present inside another rich text field or is attached at document level. This would explain why both `IsEmpty(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects)` & `curdoc.HasEmbedded` return true. Can you try to see what `curdoc.EmbeddedObjects` returns?

Comment: ok, i will try it. As you said, do i have to verify if the mail has or not the attachement on all rich text field or at document level? do we have **only solution** that will work wherever the attachement is? thanks

Comment: Yes you would have to verify if document has attachment or any rich text has it. Your second code snippet works wherever attachment is.

Comment: The answer is that there are several different ways that attachments can exist: they can be in a rich text field, and they can be a MIME parts (and MIME attachments can be in-line and not actually appear as attachments), and they can at the document level (sometimes called V2 attachments, because that's all that was available in Notes 2.x).  There are ways to handle all the cases in the back-end classes, but it's hard to get it right.  Using @AttachmentNames is a really nice hack to get past all the details.

Comment: test result : `IsEmpty(curdoc.EmbeddedObjects)`=True,`IsArray(curdoc.EmbeddedObjects)`=False

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of mail

- Notes Native = NRPC Routed, Notes Richtext or
- Mime = SMTP- Routed, Mime- Type

the attachment are stored in a different way.

In a "Pure" Notes- Mail the attachments are stored within the Richtext- Item "Body" and you can obtain them from there.

In Mime- Mails it depends on Senders- settings, Server settings and the Place where the Mail got converted From Mime to Richtext whether the Attachments can be found in the RichtextItem or in the document itself.

By the way: Mails created using iNotes or Traveler will be Mime mails too...

Knowing this the answer to your question is: There is NO single solution for both types of mail. You need to implement both to be sure.